# Apache Camel SEDA exception handling

Tags: java, apache-camel

Using Apache Camel, I need to perform XSD validation on XML files contained within zip files, with any exceptions resulting in the zip file being shifted to an error folder.

The following (simplified) route works well<sup>*</sup>:

```java
from("file:/my/Path&moveFailed=../error").split(new ZipSplitter()).
    streaming().filter(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).endsWith(".xml")).
        bean(MyCustomValidator.class).to("validator:schemas/my/schema.xsd").end();
```

In order to improve efficiency, I have tweaked it to use SEDA for the zip content checks:

```java
from("file:/my/Path&moveFailed=../error").split(new ZipSplitter()).
    streaming().filter(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).endsWith(".xml")).
        to("seda:validateEvents");

from("seda:validateEvents?concurrentConsumers=20").bean(MyValidator.class).
    to("validator:schemas/my/schema.xsd").end();
```

However, now the `moveFailed` parameter isn't being honoured from the file component. If I add an explicit `onException()` and attempt to copy files into the error folder, any XSD validation failures copies the XML files - not the zip file - into the error folder.

How can I perform parallel processing of a component while maintaining error handling for the endpoint?

<sup>*</sup>I've used an explicit file name filter for the zip file contents, otherwise the splitter executes my bean validator once for each XML file in the zip, and *once more* for the zip file itself (?!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the shareUnitOfWork option at

- http://camel.apache.org/splitter

And insted of using SEDA you can just use parallel processing in the splitter.

Comment: Thanks Claus, appreciated. I tried using parallel processing, however I was getting a stream closed IOException from ZipInputStream (even with stream caching).

Comment: I raised the the stream closed issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986515/apache-camel-zipinputstream-closed-with-parallel-processing).