# Apache Camel ZipInputStream closed with parallel processing

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am successfully using `ZipSplitter()` to process files inside a zip file. I would like to use parallel processing if possible, but calling `parallelProcessing()` results in the stream being closed prematurely. This results results in an `IOException` when the stream is being cached by `DefaultStreamCachingStrategy`.

I note that when parallel processing is enabled, `ZipIterator#checkNullAnswer(Message)` is called which closes the `ZipInputStream`. Curiously, everything is dandy if I loiter on this method in my debugger, which suggests that the iterator is being closed before processing has completed. Is this a bug or have I messed up something?

A simplified version of my route which exhibits this behaviour is:

```
from("file:myDirectory").
    split(new ZipSplitter()).streaming().parallelProcessing().
        log("Validating filename ${file:name}").
    end();
```

This is using Camel 2.13.1.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just try to apply the [CAMEL-7415](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7415) into the camel 2.13.1 branch?
 I'm not quit sure if it can fix your issue, but it is worth to give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks Willem; appreciated. It looks like that patch is already in 2.13.1, unless there's something I've missed (there's certainly a check to only call IOHelper.close() in UnmarshallProcessor if the result is an Iterator).

Comment: It looks like what's happening is that the ZipIterator closes the stream immediately after it's processed the final entry in the zip, rather than waiting for any parallel tasks to complete.

I'll see if I can implement a filthy hack for the time-being...

Comment: Actually, it looks like there are wider issues parallel processing with zip files - using it to perform parallel processing using the validator component (my zip files contain XML files) results in 'Premature end of file' SAX exceptions.

Comment: Regarding the SAX (well, empty InputStream) issue, if I loiter on ZipIterator.getNextElement() with my debugger, everything is fine. It's the same pattern as with my original issue.

Comment: It's not easy to resolve this issue without introduce some kind of call back to close the stream when the splitting work is done. I think you can fill a CAMEL JIRA for it to keep the issue in our mind.

Comment: Thanks; will do. I'm now using threads() which both works and *appears* to be functionally identical...